# Protect files that have a certain string in their names

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am relatively familiar with `.htaccess` and I know how to protect specific files. What I am looking for is a way to protect ALL files that have a specific string in their names (more specifically, files that end in a specific string, not counting the file extension). In other words, given the files

```
    filename_1.php
    filename_2.php
    filename_3_STRING.php
    filename_1_STRING.php
    File_STRING.php
```

I would like `.htaccess` to protect the last three (that end in `_STRING`), but not the first two. Did I make this clear? I'm sure that regular expressions can be used for this but clearly my expertise in the magic of RegEx is insufficient at the present time... :-) Can you help?

Comment: Are these all `.php` files, so they in fact end in `STRING.php`?

Comment: Yes, these are all .php files. But I'm generally interested in protecting all files that have a filename ending in '_STRING', irrespective of the file extension. I've commented on your reply below also. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is very similar to blocking specific files - you can use the same `<Files>` directive and a "simple" *wildcard* match - a regex is not required.

For example, to block all files that end in `_STRING` - for any file extension.

```
<Files "*_STRING.*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

The `*` wildcard matches any sequence of characters.

(Assuming you are using Apache 2.4, as opposed to Apache 2.2)

Reference:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I have no idea why I decided to complicate my life unnecessarily with RegEx! :-) I'll give this a try immediately and get back to mark this as correct if all goes smoothly. Many thanks for the prompt response.